# Bats in a number of Caves (THE BAT CAVES!!!)

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, pigeonhole-principle

This problem is kind of like a combinatorics type of problem, I believe.
But also has the feeling that it kind of makes use of the so-called "pigeonhole principle".
I recall doing a problem like this many years ago in University in a Discrete Mathematics course.

See problem below:

[image]

For the part of this problem, where any 7 caves in a row contains exactly 77 bats.
I just did simple algebra of 7K =77, and got K = 11 bats in each cave.
It satisfies the condition that there has to be at least 2 bats in every cave.
But I am getting confused as to how to handle the very beginning and very last of the caves.
Hope someone can provide some clarity on this.

Comment: What is with the down vote?

Answer (score 7):

the numbers in each cave must repeat with a period of 7, so cave 1 has the same number as cave 43 and cave 3 the same as cave 45.

Also caves 4 to 45 contain a total of $6 \times 77 = 462$ bats

- so there must be  a total of $490 - 462 = 28$ bats in caves 1, 2 and 3.
- the minimum numbers for caves 1 and 3 are 14 and 2 respectively,
- so the maximum number in cave 2 is $28 - 16 = 12$ bats.

Comment: By the same logic, the only other value possible for cave 2 is 4 bats, when caves 45 and 3 have 3 each, and cave 1 has 21.

Comment: Hi, the answer is supposedly 12 bats for Cave#2. So @WW1, you got the correct answer. But still need some time to fully get your solution

Comment: So @WW1, based on your solution, since cave1 = cave43, that  means that cave 43 has 14 bats?

Comment: @Palu (I’m not the answerer, but…) Yes, that’s right. Any six caves in a row (say caves 2 through 7) have $77-b$ bats, where $b$ is the bat count in the cave before them (cave 1)… but also the count in the cave after them (cave 8). Hence, every cave has the same count as any cave 7 spots before or after it. As for caves 4 to 45, that’s exactly 42 caves, or 6 lots of 7 caves, containing 6 lots of 77 bats. We’re told 2 is the minimum count in any cave, and cave 1 has 7 times as many as cave 45 (= caves 38, 31, 24, 17, 10, and 3), so it has at least 14.

Comment: Hi Tim Pederick, really appreciate your detailed analysis of this problem. I have to 'stare' at this longer. I always have to think more carefully and longer when the math problem is of a Discrete Mathematics realm type of problem. I need to write things out, and with the help of your analysis, I hope to get the realization !